# CSS for scrolling breadcrumb

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for creating something like this:
[Material design BreadCrumb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Adtl2.gif)

I'm stuck with the CSS. The specifications says that the object itself (the first item on the list) should has the offset 72px from the left, and that the rest of the list items should be positioned to the left of this item, and scroll as you see in the attached image.

I can't make the list scroll properly,but when I try to absolutely position something to the left, it wont scroll, if i do it to the right, it scrolls.

My HTML code is like:

```
<nav>
  <ol>
    <li><a>Object</a></li>
    <li><a>Parent 1</a></li>
    <li><a>Parent 2</a></li>
    <li><a>Parent 3</a></li>
    <li><a>Parent 4</a></li>
    ....
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please add the CSS you've tried

Comment: Bascially, I've tried move the entire list to the right so that the first item aligns 72px to the left of the viewport. I have not been able to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the help. The key insight was to use

```
direction: rtl;
padding-right: calc(100vw - 72px);
```

On the list itself so that it scrolls to the right by default including the padding, and

```
transform: translateX(100%);
margin-right: -100%;
```

On the list items to offset them by their own size to the right, while preserving proper spacing between them.

For reference if anyone else wants to do this, this is the basics:

```
nav {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 56px;
}
nav ol {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  direction: rtl;
  padding-right: calc(100vw - 72px);
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateX(100%)
  padding: 0 8px;
  margin: 0 8px 0 -100%;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Make 2 block 1 inside main block, inside block put `overflow-x:auto` and main div(block) as parent div set `heigh`t and `overflow:hidden`. you got same output as you showing on link.

```css
.breadcrumb {
  width:100%;
  height:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.insidescroll{
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  padding-bottom:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumb">
  <div class="insidescroll">
  <a href="#">Link #1</a>
  <a href="#">Link #2</a>
  <a href="#">Link #3</a>
  <a href="#">Link #4</a>
  <a href="#">Link #5</a>
  <a href="#">Link #6</a>
  <a href="#">Link #7</a>
  <a href="#">Link #8</a>
  <a href="#">Link #9</a>
  <a href="#">Link #10</a>
  <a href="#">Link #11</a>
  <a href="#">Link #12</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Karl Stefan check this output on mobile, you got same output.

Answer (score 1):

The main logic in the code was to use `webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` which makes the scroll more smooth in mobile phones

```css
nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 14px;
}
ol {
    padding: 0;
    display: table;
}
nav {
    width: 300px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
nav li a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ol>
    <li><a>Object</a></li>
    <li><a>Parent 1</a></li>
    <li><a>Parent 2</a></li>
    <li><a>Parent 3</a></li>
    <li><a>Parent 4</a></li>
    <li><a>Parent 5</a></li>
    <li><a>Parent 6</a></li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks! Problem I have now is that I want the first table-cell to be offset 72px from the left of the **viewport**, and that the rest of the cells are just pushed to the left of that as well. That is, first <li> object is position: absolute and left: 72px, or someting similar, and that this pushes the rest of the list to the left.

Comment: sorry i didnt get your point, in the example nothing was there